# How to pass a second value to another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a link to another page that passes the JobID, but I also want to pass a type string. Then if this type string is passed to the function, run the if statement.

```
e.Row.Cells[index].Text = "<a rel=\"shadowbox\" href=\"utilities/DocketViewer.aspx?JobID=" + SerNo.JobID + "\"><img src=\"images/icons/buttons/basic1-006-small.png\" alt=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" title=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" type=dbrief\"" + "\"/></a>";
```

On the page that the links sends me to I want to run an if statement like this. But the only QueryString that is passed is the JobID so it won't go into the if statement.

```
if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "dbrief")
{

}
```

How to I pass another value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put more into href, like this

```
e.Row.Cells[index].Text = "<a rel=\"shadowbox\" href=\"utilities/DocketViewer.aspx?JobID=" + SerNo.JobID + "&type=dbrief"\"><img src=\"images/icons/buttons/basic1-006-small.png\" alt=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" title=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" type=dbrief\"" + "\"/></a>";
```

you seem to have dbrief as a constant. If it was a field on SerNo you would do

```
e.Row.Cells[index].Text = "<a rel=\"shadowbox\" href=\"utilities/DocketViewer.aspx?JobID=" + SerNo.JobID + "&type=" + SerNo.dBrief + "\"><img src=\"images/icons/buttons/basic1-006-small.png\" alt=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" title=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" type=dbrief\"" + "\"/></a>";
```

edit: while we're at it, you could use string.Format for this to make it less messy

```
e.Row.Cells[index].Text = string.Format("<a rel=\"shadowbox\" href=\"utilities/DocketViewer.aspx?JobID={0}&type=dbrief\"><img src=\"images/icons/buttons/basic1-006-small.png\" alt=\"{1}\" title=\"{1}\" type=\"dbrief\"/></a>", SerNo.JobID, SerNo.JobNo);
```

you also seem to have a mistake in the speechmarks after title/type.

Comment: The QueryString returns JobID=496481&type=dbrief so it doesn't run the if statement. How do I only check the type, not the JobID? Yes dbrief is a constant

Comment: @user123456789 the code you have in your question should work ... `if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "dbrief")` is correct. Perhaps you have some other problem. Where is your querystring code? Is it in page load?

Answer (score 2):

It should be like:

```
?JobID=123&type=432
```

Keep a condition for null checking of type querystring.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the get parameter into the href attribute of the link:

```
e.Row.Cells[index].Text = "<a rel=\"shadowbox\" href=\"utilities/DocketViewer.aspx?JobID=" + SerNo.JobID + "&type=dbrief\"><img src=\"images/icons/buttons/basic1-006-small.png\" alt=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" title=\"" + SerNo.JobNo + "\" type=dbrief\"" + "\"/></a>";
```

Comment: The QueryString returns JobID=496481&type=dbrief so it doesn't run the if statement. How do I only check the type, not the JobID?

Answer (score 0):

Second Value Can be used
Ex:  `Session["type"]` = "this is the type string "

Please keep in mind these point while sending string in url

- All the attributes and values are visible to the end user.
  Therefore, they are not secure.
- There is a limit to `URL` length of  255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a `type` value then, well, pass a `type` value:

```
href=\"utilities/DocketViewer.aspx?JobID=" + SerNo.JobID + "&type=" + SerNo.Type + "\"
```

Query strings work the same way no matter how many values you include.  (Though at some point it's possible to include *too many* and the request address is too long.)